# The solutions of a system of differential equations remain in the unit disk

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that all solutions $x(t), y(t)$ of

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= -1 - y + x \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= x + xy
\end{align}

which start inside the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ must remain there for all time. Hint: Compute $$\frac{d(x^2+y^2)}{dt}$$

---

Here is what I have done. Change to polar coordinates. Let $r=x^2+y^2$. Compute $$\frac{d}{dt} (x^2+y^2)/2 = x \frac{dx}{dt}+ y \frac{dy}{dt} = x(-1-y+x) + y(x+xy) = xy^2+x^2-x = x(y^2+x-1)$$
I am trying to show that will be negative at $r=1$. This will mean the flows from the unit circle point inward. So, I think I can set $$\frac{d}{dt} (x^2+y^2)= \frac{d}{dt}(1)$$ which gives $x(y^2+x-1)=0$, hence either $x=0$, or $x=1-y^2$. Is this making sense?

Comment: It is not true, start near $(-1,0)$. This ventures outside the ball.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the system is smooth, hence it is Lipschitz on, say, $B(0,2)$.

Pick some $(x_0,y_0) \in B(0,1)$ with $x_0 <0$ and suppose the solution $(x,y)$ satisfies $(x(t),y(t)) \in B(0,1)$ for all $t \ge 0$.

Then $\dot{x}(t) = -1-y(t) + x(t)  < x(t)$ for all $t$ and so
$x(t) \le x_0 e^t$ for all $t \ge 0$, which is a contradiction.

Hence the solution is not necessarily contained in $B(0,1)$.